# custom entity admin page integrity constraints violation of managed_file in 'remove' process

Tags: forms, entities, files

I am developing a custom entity administrative page. The custom entity makes use of managed files. This is by storing a foreign key of file_id that references the file id in "file_managed" table. We've used the "managed_file" field for the form as it all matches up. It was developed that way round so we may now be paying the price for not finding a Drupal-specific implementation and instead choosing the custom FK route.

I am supplying the default_value in the recommended way:

```
$form['managed_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('A CSV file that is managed'),
    '#upload_location' => variable_get('managed_file'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('csv'),
    ),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="managed-file-element">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#default_value' => $entity->file_id,
);
```

But because of the integrity constraint we're getting this error when "Remove" is clicked:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
a foreign key constraint fails ("drupal_development"."custom_entity", 
CONSTRAINT "fk_ce_fm_fid" FOREIGN KEY ("file_id") REFERENCES "file_managed" 
("fid")): DELETE FROM {file_managed} 
WHERE  (fid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array
(
[:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 804
)
in file_delete()
```

So I worry we're at a crossroads here.

Do we do some pre or post hooks and remove the file_id from the custom entity before we let the "managed_file" field remove callback do its stuff?

Or do we restructure things more deep in our custom work to play it the Drupal way?

Either way, optional solutions would be a great help and if you could offer recommendations on which way to go that would also be great - responsibility free of course :)

Comment: Why not simply remove the FK constraint from your custom table? No other relationships are enforced in Drupal, seems that would be the simplest and most 'Drupal' solution

Comment: It's mostly ignorance and to avoid a developmental overhead tbh. There is worry that not forcing integrity constraints could see the file being deleted elsewhere and we didn't expect to have time/knowledge to setup catches for the various places that could delete files.

Comment: Drupal kinda has you covered there - it maintains a `file_usage` table, whose references are counted before a file is deleted. If you use `file_usage_add()` and implement `hook_file_delete()` in your custom entity module, that will get you the same effect while at the same time staying within the API. Referential integrity is great, but it doesn't seem worth it to me when only a single custom table (or a few tables) has it. All or nothing for me :)

Comment: I will check this out - sounds very good.